# boost::spirit::karma using the alternatives operator (|) with conditions

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-variant, boost-spirit-karma

I'm trying to generate a string from my own class called `Value` using `boost::spirit::karma`, but i got stuck with this. I've tried to extract my problem into a simple example.

I want to generate a String with karma from instances of the following class:

```
class Value
{
public:

    enum ValueType
    {
        BoolType,
        NumericType
    };

    Value(bool b) : type_(BoolType), value_(b) {}
    Value(const double d) : type_(NumericType), value_(d) {};

    ValueType type() { return type_; }

    operator bool() { return boost::get<bool>(value_); }
    operator double() { return boost::get<double>(value_); }

private:
    ValueType type_;
    boost::variant<bool, double> value_;

};
```

Here you can see what I'm tying to do:

```
int main()
{
    using karma::bool_;
    using karma::double_;
    using karma::rule;
    using karma::eps;

    std::string generated;
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(generated);

    rule<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>, Value()> value_rule = bool_ | double_;

    Value bool_value = Value(true);
    Value double_value = Value(5.0);

    karma::generate(sink, value_rule, bool_value);
    std::cout << generated << "\n";

    generated.clear();

    karma::generate(sink, value_rule, double_value);
    std::cout << generated << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The first call to `karma::generate()` works fine because the value is a bool and the first generator in my rule also "consumes" a bool. But the second `karma::generate()` fails with `boost::bad_get` because karma tries to eat a bool and calls therefore `Value::operator bool()`.

My next thought was to modify my generator rule and use the `eps()` generator together with a condition but here i got stuck:

```
value_rule = (eps( ... ) << bool_) | (eps( ... ) << double_);
```

I'm unable to fill the brackets of the eps generator with sth. like this (of course not working):

```
eps(value.type() == BoolType)
```

I've tried to get into `boost::phoenix`, but my brain seems not to be ready for things like this.

Please help me!

here is my full example (compiling but not working):
[main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/Cm57dVja)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing that comes to mind is: use the `value_` variant (as variants are very well-supported by Karma).

Using a phoenix bind inside the semantic action would work:

```
rule<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>, Value()> value_rule;

value_rule = (bool_ | double_) 
    [ _1 = phx::bind(&Value::value_, _val) ];
```

Although this requires exposing `value_` (to *friends* e.g.) so you might prefer an accessor method.

Here is a working example **http://liveworkspace.org/code/22ab2093ad9bd3b03e55a7f3dde952f8**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

class Value
{
public:

    enum ValueType
    {
        BoolType,
        NumericType
    };

    Value(bool b) : type_(BoolType), value_(b) {}
    Value(double d) : type_(NumericType), value_(d) {};

    ValueType type() { return type_; }

    operator bool()   { return boost::get<bool>(value_);   }
    operator double() { return boost::get<double>(value_); }

  private:
    ValueType type_;

    friend int main();
    boost::variant<bool, double> value_;
};

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main()
{
    using namespace karma;
    std::string generated;
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(generated);

    rule<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>, Value()> value_rule;

    value_rule = (bool_ | double_) 
        [ _1 = phx::bind(&Value::value_, _val) ];

    Value bool_value = Value(true);
    Value double_value = Value(5.0);

    karma::generate(sink, value_rule, bool_value);
    std::cout << generated << "\n";

    generated.clear();
    karma::generate(sink, value_rule, double_value);
    std::cout << generated << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
true
5.0
```

Off-topic: May I suggest marking the *conversion operators* `explicit` (at the very least), to avoid nasty surprises?